# Angularfire2 Remove 2 entries from different nodes with same ID

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have a Booking application using Angular 2 and Firebase, using Angularfire 2. When a booking is made, I have 2 nodes created in Firebase. The single entry shares the same orderID as follows:

[Bookings Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l594c.png)
[Orders Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gve7E.png)

Node 1: Bookings
Node 2: Orders

I have to have it this way to help with other functions.

When I remove (delete) the order from the application, I cannot get it to remove the specific entry in the Orders Node and Bookings node with the matching ID. Only removes from Orders Node.

Here is the HTML Button with the Delete function:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="button" (click)="orderDelete(order.$key)"><em class="fa fa-trash-o"></em></button>
```

and here is the constructor getting access to the orders node in Firebase:

```
    constructor(public af: AngularFire, public toastr: ToastrService, public router: Router) {
    this.ordersData = af.database.list('/orders');
    this.ordersData.subscribe((res) => {
      this.orders = res;
      console.log(this.orders)
    });
  }
```

This is the function that runs when I hit Delete, to delete the order:

```
 orderDelete(key) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) {
      this.ordersData.remove(key).then((res) => {
        this.toastr.success('Order Deleted Successfully!', 'Success!');
      })
    }
  }
```

I need to figure out, when I delete the order, (which is working ok) it will delete the entry in the bookings node with the matching ID.

I am not sure if I have to do a query in the constructor to get the booking and order entry and match there ID's first then delete that result?

Any help would be fantastic, thank you.

---

UPDATE: Alomost 24 hours later and I still cannot work this out, do you think something like this would work? where I run a query to try and delete the booking from the 'Booking Node' who's 'orderId' matches the 'orderId' of the data from the 'Orders' node? forgive me if this is ridiculous, I have tried everything to get this to work and I am literally trying anything I can to get this to work.

```
this.toDelete = af.database.list('/bookings', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'orderId',
        equalTo: ordersData.orderId 
      }
    });
```

---

UPDATE: Still no progress, what I have tried now is the following within the orderDelete() function.

```
 orderDelete(key) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) {

      const bookings = this.af.database.list('/bookings', {
      preserveSnapshot: true,
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'orderId',
        equalTo: this.orderId
      }
    });
    bookings.subscribe(snapshots=>{
        snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
          snapshot.ref.remove();
        });
    })

      this.ordersData.remove(key).then((res) => {
        this.toastr.success('Order Deleted Successfully!', 'Success!');
      })
    }
  }
```

My thoughts behind this was to first query the bookings, then query the orderId within the bookings then try to delete this booking associated with this order, however this did not work either.

---

UPDATE: Still no luck, I have tried this now.

I decided to add another click function to the html like so:

```
(click)="orderDelete(order.$key); bookingDelete(booking.$key)"
```

So instead of just running the orderDelete function to delete the order, I thought perhaps if I replicate the function for the bookings node that might work. So I did this also in my TS file:

```
   orderDelete(key) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) {
      this.ordersData.remove(key).then((res) => {
        this.toastr.success('Order Deleted Successfully!', 'Success!');
      })
    }
  }

  bookingDelete(key) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) {
      this.bookingData.remove(key).then((res) => {
        this.toastr.success('Booking Deleted Successfully!', 'Success!');
      })
    }
  }
```

So the thing is it does delete the specific order in the orders node using the orderDelete(key) function but the bookingDelete(key)function deletes the entire bookings node altogether instead of the selected item to delete :(

Back to the drawing board I guess.

I have no clue why when running the orderDelete function it does delete the selected item and why when running the bookingDelete function it deletes all bookings in the node?

---

UPDATE: I Think I have done it!!

I worked around with the code, the only thing I did was change the 2 functions, so I am still running 2 functions from the click action in the HTML. Here is what I have done:

```
 orderDelete(key) {
    this.selectedBooking = {
        orderId : key.orderId
      }

    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) {
      this.ordersData.remove(key).then((res) => {
        this.toastr.success('Order Deleted Successfully!', 'Success!');
      })
    }
  }




  bookingDelete(orderId){
        this.af.database.list('/bookings', {
        query:{
            orderByChild: 'orderId',
            equalTo: orderId
          }
       }).subscribe(res=>{
           let key = res[0].$key;
           this.bookingData.remove(key)
       });
    }
```

I created a variable with a null value called selectedBooking at the top above the constructor like so: selectedBooking = null;
In the orderDelete() function I assigned the 'key.orderId' to an orderId variable. I then passed this new orderId variable as a parameter to the bookingDelete() function with an added query to query the orderId which is equal to the passed orderId then run the remove function.

I dont even know if this code is 100% correct, but it worked and removed the booking and the matching order from the bookings node and orders node.

If you think there could be an issue with the code please let me know.

Thank you, I hope this can help someone in anyway :)